# TaskQueue equivalent in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, google-app-engine, task-queue, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Shifting from App Engine to AWS/Beanstalk, I have a PHP server that will post-process uploaded files asynchronously.

In App Engine, all I had to do was something like:

```
(new PushTask('/workerRoute', $taskParams))->add();
```

And the async worker operation would've been executed once a file was uploaded.

I would like to know if there's such an **easy/simple** equivalent in AWS/Beanstalk?

The solution path I'm heading in AWS is far from simple.

To the best of my understanding, I'll need to:

1. Create a worker environment

   - Upload the code base
   - Have an admin sync permissions so that the machines will communicate
2. Create a dedicated SQS queue
3. Create an S3 bucket rule that will post an message to the above SQS upon file upload
4. Have the worker process the SQS message

   - Since I can't control parameters, I'll need to somehow embed them into the S3 file path and then extract them in the worker

Any simplification towards a TaskQueue-like behavior would be highly appreciated. 10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push messages from the script, as you did with AppEngine: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-sqs.html Your `$taskParams` is a `messageBody`.

Comment: I figured out earlier that I can let the files upload to my web server and when a file is uploaded, shift it to S3 using putObject() and then place an SQS message with all the parameters I need wrapped up as a JSON payload. Still, no way to do have the push handler done automatically - I still need to raise a worker machine for that part, right?

Comment: Depends on your usecase. s3 can send an event either to SQS or Lambda. If you feel like s3 event has enough information for your worker to process it, you can do it as you described in the question. Having a separate 'uploader' service you have more flexibility of building the SQS message with extra data you get on file upload.

Comment: Alright, +1 + accepted answer based on the fact that I don't see a shorter route than web-server + worker and the fact that you did offer an improvement. Thanks.